# Sub-group and group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Given two groups $G$ and $H$ and a homomorphism $i:G\rightarrow H$. It is clear that the image $i(G)$ is again a sub-group of $H$, if the mapping $i$ is injective.

**Question:** What if $i$ is not injective? Does the image still forms a subgroup? If not, why?

Comment: It is always a subgroup. This has been shown here several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x,y \in i(G)$. Then there exists $g,h \in G$ such that $i(g)=x$ and $i(h)=y$.

Then $x\cdot y = i(g)\cdot i(h) = i(g\cdot h) \in i(G)$ since $i$ is a homomorphism (2nd equality) and $G$ is a group ($g\cdot h \in G$.).

Now take $x \in i(G)$. Then again there is $g \in G$ such that $i(g)=x$.

I claim that the inverse of $i(g)$ is $i(g)^{-1}=i(g^{-1})$. Indeed:

$i(g)\cdot i(g^{-1}) = i(g \cdot g^{-1}) = i(e_G) = e_H$. Similarly $i(g^{-1})\cdot i(g) = e_H$.

It should also be clear that $e_H$ is the identity in $i(G)$.